# Analogue to log4net ThreadContext.Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, log4net, serilog

Log4net has a ThreadContext class that has a Properties property. We need an analogue of this functionality with Serilog or other technology in .NET (ASP.NET Core)

We need an analague of the log4net ThreadContext.Properties functionality in .NET (ASP.NET Core)

Answer (score 2):

In Serilog, we have `LogContext` class which is analogous to `ThreadContext` from Log4net. Both have the property `Properties` (dictionary) to store the contextual information.

You can checkout the documentation here - https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment

Do let me know if this was helpful!

Comment: Are you sure about that? The point of `ThreadContext` is that it store the properities against a single thread. I’m not seeing that in the Serilog docs page you link to. _” The ThreadContext stores data in a thread local slot. This is attached
to a specific runtime thread.  **The ThreadContext data is limited to that one thread
and not visible from other threads.**”_ - from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080408094216/http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F15288%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx)